# uWSGI - ImportError: No module named os

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

This is puzzling, because uWSGI works when running:

```
uwsgi --http :8003 --wsgi-file bigsky.wsgi
```

But doesn't work with:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --no-site
```

It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bigsky.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
```

This is being deployed with:

- python 3.4
- django 1.8
- Centos 7
- uWSGI 2.0.11

Here's the code:

**uwsgi.ini:**

```
[uwsgi]
# %d is the dir this configuration file is in

socket = 127.0.0.1:8003
chmod-socket = 666

uid = bsdev
gid = bsdev

master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 4

# virtualenv
home = /home/bsdev/.virtualenvs/bs_py34

chdir = /www/django/releases/persistent/bsrs/python3/
wsgi-file = project.wsgi

env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.persistent

# create a pidfile
pidfile = /tmp/project-master.pid 
harakiri = 10 # respawn processes taking more than 20 seconds
max-requests = 5000 # respawn processes after serving 5000 requests

# will be run via `supervisord` so don't need to daemonize
# logto = /var/log/uwsgi/project.log
logdate = true
vacuum = true
```

**project.wsgi:**

```
import os
import sys


# python 3
sys.path.append('/usr/local/bin/python3.4')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')

# project
sys.path.append('/www/django/releases/persistent/bsrs/python3')
sys.path.append('/www/django/releases/persistent/bsrs/bsrs-django')
sys.path.append('/www/django/releases/persistent/bsrs/bsrs-django/project')
sys.path.append('/www/django/releases/persistent/bsrs/bsrs-django/project/project')


# 1st instantiate wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
_application = get_wsgi_application()

# Add the app directories to the PYTHONPATH
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings.persistent'


def application(environ, start_response):
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

**Edit:**

I am also getting this error message.  It says *Python version: 2.7.5*, but the Django App should be running in python 3.4.  Is this a possible issue?

```
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/bigsky.sock fd 3
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - Python version: 2.7.5 (default, Jun 24 2015, 00:41:19)  [GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)]
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - Set PythonHome to /home/bsdev/.virtualenvs/bs_py34/
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x25258f0
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - python threads support enabled
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - mapped 363840 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
Tue Sep 22 13:25:12 2015 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bigsky/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
```

Comment: I had this once. I think it's the python plugin misbehaving. Try installing uwsgi into virtualenv with pip and running from there - this usually gets you a more compatible uwsgi.

Comment: I put the answer below, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this issue, because I had not compliled uWSGI correctly on Centos 7, and needed to then build it with Python 3.4.  In short, here are the commands:

```
wget http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-2.0.3.tar.gz
tar -xvf uwsgi-2.0.3.tar.gz
cd uwsgi-2.0.3

source ~/path/to/virtualenv_python3.4/bin/activate

python uwsgiconfig.py --build
```

Then run uWSGI:

```
sudo ~/misc/uwsgi-2.0.3/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using python3, so install `uwsgi` with `pip3`

`pip3 install uwsgi`

Comment: but what if some of the projects are on python 3 and some on are python 2

Comment: Just run it, no problem. I also got those condition.
On my configuration, each project has uwsgi.ini and declare the specific python version in `plugins`.